# Page is still loading even after Page.LoadComplete()

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, ckeditor, delay

I want to disable some controls on my web page, whilst the page is loading based on a change to a `DropDownList` control

When the user changes the DropDownList, I have code in there to disable the control temporarily.

```
myDDL.enabled =false;
```

I also have on my `Page_Load()` a call to create the `LoadComplete` event.

```
Page.LoadComplete += new EventHandler(Page_LoadComplete);
```

In the `LoadComplete()` I simply re-enable the `DropDownList` control

```
myDDL.enabled=true;
```

However, what's really happening is that my control is enabled "very quickly", and the user can still change the value of the `dropdownlist,` even though the page is still "loading".

What do I mean by "loading"?

I have a `gridview` with `CKeditor` textboxes over several rows, and I can see the `gridview` has loaded, but the `CKeditor` control is still rendering before it stops, due to what ever it's doing internally (javascript) to load.

Is there a way I can delay the `LoadComplete()` event say 5 seconds, to allow the javascript in CKeditor to finish?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the delima by simply using Javascript and ...

```
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function() { 
        var ddl = document.getElementById('<%=myDDL.ClientID%>');
        if (ddl) ddl.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }, 4500)
}
```

This delayed the dropdownlist control from being re-enabled for 4.5 seconds, and AFTER all javascript and other controls have been loaded.

I know the onLoad() runs immediately after the DOM has loaded, but with the delay, the control is re-enabled only when I want it to.

Works great!

Answer (score 1):

if all you want is a 5 section delay, you can do this:

function loadComplete() {

```
 setTimeout(function(){ myDDL.enable = true;}, 5000);
```

}

this will cause the ddl to be enabled 5 seconds after loadComplete is called.

So what I actually do is on server:

```
 private void load_page (){
     myDD.enable = false;
}
```

then on the client, with jquery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { $("#myDDL").prop('disabled', false); });

</script>
```

without jquery, you would use the onload event handler as part of your forms.

This solution is strictly client side but assumes an aspx page.  The onload event handler was assigned in the  tag.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function init() {
            document.getElementById("someDDL").disabled = false;

        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form onload="init()">
        <asp:DropDownList id="someDDL" clientIdMode="Static" runat="server" Enabled="false"></asp:DropDownList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But that's javascript. Do you have a C# solution please?

Comment: There isn't one.  You want the ddl to be disabled until the page is loaded. You need to do that on the client (hence javascript) not the server.

Comment: Thanks. Ok I've done this, but the ddl is always false at the start! I want it to be enabled, so the user can choose something, but when they've chosen a value, disable it. Then trigger the change event, load the gridview, CKeditors, etc... and then have the ddl re-enabled again after ALL OBJECTS have loaded on the page (including CKeditor etc).

Comment: And also, what calls loadComplete()?